# Proxy to access OAuth2 password grant type REST API

Tags: docker, rest, oauth-2.0, proxy

I have an application that runs in a Docker container and it needs to consume an external REST API. The external REST API is secured with OAuth2 Password Grant Type (`client_id`, `client_secret`, `user_name` and `password`). The application does not support this type of authentication though.

I thought about a solution to run another container with some lightweight proxy. It would handle the token request, caching and related stuf and expose the proxied REST API without any security. The two containers will share a docker network `"proxy"` that will keep the insecured REST API to the application only.

I have two questions:

1. Is it a good idea at all?
2. Is there any lightweight proxy with easy configuration to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your backend app should operate in a standard way, as an OAuth client. This will involve your app sending an access token to the external API, in the HTTP authorization header.

The call to get the external token should only be made occasionally, then cached in memory. Use of filter / helper classes is the best way to externalize such responsibilities from business logic, while remaining secure.

Avoid introducing unprotected endpoints inside your backend that might be exploited at a future time. Instead follow a `zero trust` approach to APIs and business data, where both internal and external endpoints are secured. This is preferred over older `perimeter security` approaches.

All of the above should be possible with only simple code, so is recommended whenever dealing with secured data.

Comment: Both the REST API and the application are third party and I cannot modify them.